# generic function callback with Eigen types as parameters

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm trying to pass a function using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) objects as inputs and outputs as a callback to another function. I can't find a way to properly handle `const` parameters. For example I have this copy function :

```
//a generic function copying a matrix into another
template<
  typename DerivedV1,
  typename DerivedV2
  >
void copy
(
  const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> & v1,
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> const & v2 //Eigen const hack, this is not const
)
{
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> & v2_cast = 
    const_cast< Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> & >(v2) ;
  v2_cast = v1 ;
}
```

I know that [output parameters can be considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447789/best-practices-for-functions-with-multiple-eigen-objects-as-parameters) but I'm trying to follow [the coding guidelines of libigl](http://libigl.github.io/libigl/style-guidelines/#returns-vs-output-parameters). As a reference I call this function within another function, this will work.

```
//reference non generic behaviour
template<
  typename DerivedV1,
  typename DerivedV2
  >
void reference
(
  const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> & V1,
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> & V2 //Eigen const hack not necessary for the example
) 
{
  copy(V1.row(0), V2.row(0)) ;
}
```

Now I would like genericity on the copy function.

```
//generic without constness,deduction fails with a template function as a parameter
template<
  typename DerivedV1,
  typename DerivedV2,
  typename Callback
  >
void generic
(
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> & V1, //no const here, this is my problem
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> & V2,
  Callback callback
) 
{
  callback(V1.row(0), V2.row(0)) ;
}
```

But automatic template deduction from parameters will not deduce the template parameters for the callback. The only solution I found so far is this ugly overload, I'm not proud of it, and open for suggestions.

```
//overload to help template deduction
template<
  typename DerivedV1,
  typename DerivedV2
  >
void generic
(
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> & V1,
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> & V2,
  void(*callback)(
    const Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> &>().row(0)) > &, 
    Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> &>().row(0)) > const &
  )
) 
{
  generic<
    DerivedV1, 
    DerivedV2, 
    void(*)(
      const Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> &>().row(0)) > &, 
      Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> &>().row(0)) > const &
    )
    >(V1, V2, callback) ;
}
```

and this works, but I can't manage to handle a `const` in the first parameter of `generic` :

```
//desired generic with the const parameter
template<
  typename DerivedV1,
  typename DerivedV2,
  typename Callback
  >
void generic_const
(
  const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> & V1, //here is the desired const
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> & V2,
  Callback callback
) 
{
  callback(V1.row(0), V2.row(0)) ;
}

//attempt for an overload to help template deduction
template<
  typename DerivedV1,
  typename DerivedV2
  >
void generic_const
(
  const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> & V1,
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> & V2,
  void(*callback)(
    const Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> &>().row(0)) > &, 
    Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> &>().row(0)) > const &
  )
) 
{
  generic_const<
    DerivedV1, 
    DerivedV2, 
    void(*)(
      const Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> &>().row(0)) > &, 
      Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> &>().row(0)) > const &
    )
    >(V1, V2, callback) ;
}

int main() {
  Eigen::Matrix3f m1 ;
  m1.setRandom() ;

  Eigen::Matrix3f m2 ;
  m2.setRandom() ;

  std::cout << "== random m1 ==" << std::endl << m1 << std::endl ;
  std::cout << "== random m2 ==" << std::endl << m2 << std::endl ;

  reference(m1, m2) ;

  std::cout << "== reference behaviour ==" << std::endl << m2 << std::endl ;

  m2.setRandom() ;

  std::cout << "== random m2 ==" << std::endl << m2 << std::endl ;

  //this is ok
  generic(m1, m2, copy) ;
  //this will not compile

  std::cout << "== final m2 ==" << std::endl << m2 << std::endl ;

  return 0 ;
}
```

Here is the error

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 
‘const Eigen::MatrixBase<const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 3>, 1, 3, false> >&’ 
from expression of type 
‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 3> >::ConstRowXpr’ 
{aka ‘const Eigen::Block<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 3>, 1, 3, false>’}
```

The full example is in the following snippet.

```js
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

//a generic function copying a matrix into another
template<
  typename DerivedV1,
  typename DerivedV2
  >
void copy
(
  const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> & v1,
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> const & v2 //Eigen const hack, this is not const
)
{
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> & v2_cast = 
    const_cast< Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> & >(v2) ;
  v2_cast = v1 ;
}

//reference non generic behaviour
template<
  typename DerivedV1,
  typename DerivedV2
  >
void reference
(
  const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> & V1,
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> & V2 //Eigen const hack is not necessary in this example
) 
{
  copy(V1.row(0), V2.row(0)) ;
}

//generic without constness,deduction fails with a template function as a parameter
template<
  typename DerivedV1,
  typename DerivedV2,
  typename Callback
  >
void generic
(
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> & V1, //no const here this is my problem
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> & V2,
  Callback callback
) 
{
  callback(V1.row(0), V2.row(0)) ;
}

//overload to help template deduction
template<
  typename DerivedV1,
  typename DerivedV2
  >
void generic
(
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> & V1,
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> & V2,
  void(*callback)(
    const Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> &>().row(0)) > &, 
    Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> &>().row(0)) > const &
  )
) 
{
  generic<
    DerivedV1, 
    DerivedV2, 
    void(*)(
      const Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> &>().row(0)) > &, 
      Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> &>().row(0)) > const &
    )
    >(V1, V2, callback) ;
}

//desired generic with the const parameter
template<
  typename DerivedV1,
  typename DerivedV2,
  typename Callback
  >
void generic_const
(
  const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> & V1,
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> & V2,
  Callback callback
) 
{
  callback(V1.row(0), V2.row(0)) ;
}

//attempt for an overload to help template deduction
template<
  typename DerivedV1,
  typename DerivedV2
  >
void generic_const
(
  const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> & V1,
  Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> & V2,
  void(*callback)(
    const Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> &>().row(0)) > &, 
    Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> &>().row(0)) > const &
  )
) 
{
  generic_const<
    DerivedV1, 
    DerivedV2, 
    void(*)(
      const Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV1> &>().row(0)) > &, 
      Eigen::MatrixBase< decltype(std::declval< Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV2> &>().row(0)) > const &
    )
    >(V1, V2, callback) ;
}

int main() {
  Eigen::Matrix3f m1 ;
  m1.setRandom() ;

  Eigen::Matrix3f m2 ;
  m2.setRandom() ;

  std::cout << "== random m1 ==" << std::endl << m1 << std::endl ;
  std::cout << "== random m2 ==" << std::endl << m2 << std::endl ;

  reference(m1, m2) ;

  std::cout << "== reference behaviour ==" << std::endl << m2 << std::endl ;

  m2.setRandom() ;

  std::cout << "== random m2 ==" << std::endl << m2 << std::endl ;

  generic(m1, m2, copy) ;
  generic_const(m1, m2, copy) ;

  std::cout << "== final m2 ==" << std::endl << m2 << std::endl ;

  return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle overloads, pass functor instead of function, something like:

```
auto copy_functor = [](auto&& source, auto&& dest){ return copy(source, dest); }

generic(m1, m2, copy_functor);
generic_const(m1, m2, copy_functor);
```

Comment: It works. I just can't understand how the compiler is able to deduce those auto, but not able to deduce the template parameters for copy in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: This basically creates a _transparent_ functor like `struct functor { template<typename src,typename dst> void operator()(src&&,dst&&) {...} };`

Comment: Ah ! I think I get it. The template is on the method, not the struct ! Therefore the type of the struct and therefore the function taking it as a parameter can be determined, and the deduction of the template parameters of copy is deferred.